# React folder structure don't reload changes

Tags: reactjs, import, directory, jsx

I'm starting a new project using create-react-app. I've made some stateless components in a folder structure but now the changes I do in any component doesn't reload the browser to reflect those changes (for example changing the message "This is a test!" to another message). Any idea?

***EDIT: Solved in comments! The problem was my OS (Ubuntu) default watchers (about 8000). Augmenting them solved the problem (now 500000 watchers).***

**Folder Structure**

```
-public
 |-index.html
-src
 |-components
   |-containers
   | |-App
   |   |--App.jsx
   |-presentational
     |-GenerateProposal
      |--GenerateProposal.jsx
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

import GenerateProposal from '../../presentational/GenerateProposal/GenerateProposal/';

const App = () => (
    <div className="App">
        <GenerateProposal />
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

**GenerateProposal.jsx**

```
import React from 'react;
import { PageHeader } from 'react-bootstrap;

const GenerateProposal = () => (
    <PageHeader>This is a test!</PageHeader>
);

export default GenerateProposal;
```

Comment: Sometimes the change watch doesn't see new files. Try to restart the dev server (the one started with 'npm start').

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @DanglingCruze I'm using VSCode

Comment: @bogdanpetru Not working, I'm using standard "npm start" (react-scripts start). When I Change the message "This is a test!" it doesn't show until I restart the server...

Comment: Does this helps? https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-start-doesnt-detect-changes

Comment: @DanglingCruze Actually I'm not using Webpack and most of the tips are just for Webpack uses :(

Comment: You're using create-react-app which internally uses webpack.

Comment: Add a component where you change this PageHeader

Comment: @DanglingCruze Actually it worked! I am working on Linux and I needed to augment my watchers (default was 8196, now about 500000)

Comment: That is awesome :)